# Header Manipulation: SMTP

Tags: java, smtp, fortify

I'm facing an issue where fortify is failing due to

> Header Manipulation: SMTP

I tried multiple solutions. However, fortify still fails.

My code as below:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> sendEmail(EmailBody parameters, String form) {
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
    String emailSubjectValue = parameters.getEmailSubject();

    // Check email subject for Manipulation

    if (isHeaderInjection(emailSubjectValue)) {
      result.put("error", "invalid email Subject");
      return result;
    }

    try{
    ....
      message.setSubject(emailSubjectValue, "UTF-8");
    }...

    private static boolean isHeaderInjection(String value) {
    if (value == null)
        return false;
    else if ((value.indexOf('\n') != -1 || value.indexOf('\r') != -1) || value.indexOf("%0A") != -1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

    }
}
```

Even though I'm doing the check before setting the emailSubject, the scan still fails.

Would you please let me know if there is any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you have to avoid any CRLF inside an mail subject

Since SMTP Header Manipulation vulnerabilities occur when an application includes malicious data in its output, one logical approach is to validate data immediately before it is used in the header context and make sure there are no illegal CRLF characters that can break the header structure.

Before setting the subject you may make sure that this won't happen by using:

```
String normalizedSubject = StringUtils.normalizeSpace(emailSubjectValue);
```